# Obtaining correct UTF-8 characters from a Percent Encoded URL parameter

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having some trouble with the dreaded UTF-8 Character Encoding! It's driving me insane, no matter which way I approach it or how many online guides I follow, I can never get it to return the desired results. Here's what's going on:

- My whole website uses a simple text-file database that is UTF-8 encoded, and it correctly shows all manner of special characters, latin, arabic, japanese, you name it, they all show correctly, with one exception:
- When the user uses the "Search" input box I have on my website, I use $search = $_REQUEST['search']; to get the input data on the results page and show results accordingly. When a user inserts special characters in the search box, they get "Percent Encoded" in the URL (for example, "ï" becomes "%E3%AF"). When showing $string in the actual website, any special character appears as � (black diamond with question mark).
- I have tried everthing it says here http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/ with the exception of the header(). I have set the charset as UTF-8 in my head section with an http-equiv meta but for some reason whenever I set it as a header() my PHP stylesheet stops working (and the character problem remains). Maybe this is a clue?
- I have tried urldecode and rawurldecode too, but they don't change anything.
- Keep in mind special characters appear correctly elsewhere on the site, it's only with the $search string where this problem appears. As a side-note, even though the characters are not visualizing correctly, my search engine does actually interpret the special characters correctly when filtering the results. This makes me understand that the special character is actually there and correctly encoded, but it's just a matter of making it visualize correctly with the correct charset. However... everything appears to be UTF-8.

To be honest I'm so confused about this that this question might also appear to be confusing and the information I'm giving you might not be very well structured either, so I apologize and will try to provide more detailed information for any questions.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: `ï` is not `%E3%AF` but `%C3%AF` in UTF-8. `%E3%AF` is as far as I know not valid in UTF-8.

Comment: @deceze Well, while it's a very in-depth guide, I haven't been able to fix my problem. I've added accept-charset="utf-8" to the input form but this does not help. Curiously, when trying to get $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'], even when sending the header(), I get an Undefined Index error.

Comment: @nkr hmm, Interesting! I think this might be a good clue. In any case, even manually setting &search=ï in the URL still makes the � symbol appear in it's place on the website.

Comment: Did you try to setup a simple page which does nothing than showing an input field and the given input after submitting?

Comment: @nkr I made a test page with just the form and the $_REQUEST function. It actually works when I specify the charset with the meta http-equiv!! This however fails on my site... I'm confused.

Comment: Is there some function in your code which alters `$_REQUEST` before you read it? Can you add some code?

Comment: @nkr ok! we are getting very close! I ommited the "cleanup" function I use on the $search string and it now works. However, I don't see which part can be affecting it. Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/VwUGf5GB

Comment: @nkr I've found the cause. strtolower is making it not understand %XX! Please tell me how I can upvote you!

Comment: @juanitojuandejuanes: I added an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure not to have any function which alters your `$_REQUEST`. Some functions are not aware of special encodings.

The best way to investigate is checking the state of the variables before and after they are altered.

Comment: Thankyou, your simple logical analysis of the situation made me find the cause of the error in a completely unexpected place!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add one thing more point regarding utf-8 string manipulation.

When manipulating utf-8 strings always use multibyte string functions.

use  `mb_strtolower` in place of `strtolower()`

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php.

Comment: This has also helped me further on down the line, thank you. Although I've come across "mb_convert_case" too. Which is the standard?

Comment: Internally 'mb_convert_case' use 'mb_strtolower','mb_strtoupper'.... I would prefer 'mb_strtolower'. Not sure about any standard.